# Ibm worklight apis on each page of multipage hybrid application

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

Can we access the api of ibm worklight on each page of multipage hybrid application..Just like we can access cordova apis  in phonegap by referencing it on each page..is there any thing of that sort in ibm worklight for worklight json storage api access on each page? is there any workaround by which i would be able to access the json storage on each page

Answer (score 0):

IBM Mulitpage applications are all processed in One Page HTML via,

1. Any Framworks like JqueryMobile,
2. Or via Loading the content into the `index.html` Page via `.load()` like Api's.

So you will be able to access all the Worklight and also Cordova API's in your App, since in both the ways we use single HTML page.

[Information Regarding Multipage Applications](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/client-side-development-basics/building-multi-page-application/)